# How to do complex annotations( and how to think about it!)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to annotate my Product objects with a total_item_sold field. and I can't seem to get my head around it. So, any explanation as to how I should do this will be greatly appreciated.

```
class Order(models.Model):
   ...

class OrderPayment(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    successful = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

class OrderListItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    list_item = models.ForeignKey(ListItem)
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class List(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="lists", through="ListItem")
    ....


class ListItem(models.Model):
    llist = models.ForeignKey(List)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...
```

so for each product, I want to find all OrderPayments that have been "succesful" and have that product in them( which is resolved by  finding the OrderListItems then ListItems and then products), and then annotate the product with total_items_sold of that product.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: the thing is that I am stuck! I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @rudda yes it is right, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships